# How to separately deploy alfresco share application and alfresco repository on different tomcat server?

Tags: alfresco

Currently, I am deploying both "share.war" and "alfresco.war" on same tomcat server.
So, how can I separately deploy "share.war" and "alfresco.war" on different tomcat servers?

I want to deploy "share.war" on tomcat server 1, deploy "alfresco.war" on tomcat server 2.

Comment: Do you mean run the Share webapp on a different machines to the Alfresco webapp? Or some sort of different slicing up?

Comment: In high level architecture of alfresco,we have (1)alfresco web scripts tier,(2)alfresco repository tier (3) and database tier.Alfresco repository provide so many services and API.how can i repository services host on other machine?

Comment: There are two sets of webscripts in Alfresco, those that live in the alfresco.war, and those in the share.war. You can put Share (UI + its webscritps) on another machine easily, the repository tier webscripts require direct access to the rest of the repo so have to live together.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to embed Alfresco in your application, you should check this old but still mostly valid [webinar](http://blogs.alfresco.com/wp/webcasts/2009/07/alfresco-webcast-why-and-how-to-embed-alfresco/).

If you want to have a quick start at running Alfresco outside any application container (i.e. directly bootstrapping the Spring context) the *FirstFoundationClient* sample in the [Alfresco SDK](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Alfresco_SDK_3.4) is what you need.

Answer (score 1):

This is really much more simple than it seems. Deploy the wars on separate tomcats, and then configure share-config-custom.xml inside /shared/alfresco/web-extension on the Share deployment to point to the Alfresco repository. It's that easy.

Answer (score 0):

From a copy-paste of the [official documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.0/tasks/share-tomcat-deploy.html) :

> You can run the Share application in a separate Tomcat instance from
>   the instance running the Alfresco WAR. This additional instance can be
>   installed on the same server as the original Tomcat instance, or it
>   can be installed on a separate server.

1. Install a new Tomcat instance on the same server at the original Tomcat instance.
2. Modify the **/conf/server.xml** file for the new Tomcat instance:

   1. Change the port number (for example, to 8006) in this line:

      ```
      <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
      ```
   2. Change the port number (for example, to 8180) in this line:

      ```
      <!-- Define a non-SSL HTTP/1.1 Connector on port 8080 --> 
      <Connector port="8080" ....
      ```
3. Move the share.war file from the original Tomcat /webapps directory to the new Tomcat /webapps directory.
4. (Optional) Configure the original Alfresco Tomcat deployment.
5. Start the original Tomcat.

   You can use Alfresco supplied batch files.
6. If you are running the Share Tomcat instance on a separate machine, you must modify the override file in the Share Tomcat web-extension directory:

   1. Open the share-config-custom.xml file.
   2. Change any instance of the server and port to the correct name or IP address of the Alfresco server.

      ```
       http://yourserver:8080
      ```

      Save the file.
   3. Start the new Share Tomcat instance.